# How do run a program at startup?

Tags: 13.04, startup

I'm trying to make Firefox run when users log on (and go to a specific page if possible), but I'm not sure how.

Using Ubuntu 13.04, I can enter the Startup Applications Preferences (by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and typing `gnome-session-properties`). However, after clicking `Add` when browsing for a command, I'm a bit stumped.

Where would I need to point to in order to start Firefox? I did try putting just `http://www.mywebsite.com/`, but that did nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/usr/bin/firefox` should do it. You can even specify a webpage to open:

```
/usr/bin/firefox http://www.google.com/
```

If you are ever stumped as to where to find a specific command, run `which <command>` in a terminal to find out where it is.

Comment: Done. It's very annoying that it won't let you do it right away!