# Rc.Local works manually but not at boot

Tags: screen, startup

This is what i got with

```
systemctl status rc-local.service
```

```
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 rc.local[2157]: No protocol specified
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 rc.local[2157]: Error: Can't open display: (null)
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 rc.local[2157]: Failed creating new xdo instance
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 sudo[2161]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/firefox -url "theurl"
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 sudo[2161]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 rc.local[2157]: No protocol specified
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 rc.local[2157]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 rc.local[2157]: Unable to init server: Impossible de se connecter : Connexion refusée
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 rc.local[2157]: Error: cannot open display: :0.0
- déc. 07 16:09:48 PKPIE01 sudo[2161]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

And this is what i execute in my `/etc/rc.local` working when I run

```
sudo /etc/rc.local
```

in terminal but doesn't work at restart :

```
sleep 45s

export DISPLAY=:0.0 xdotool

export DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox

sudo /usr/bin/firefox -url "the url"

exit 0
```

Any clues ? I'm really new to this, so if you have any good advices or best practices, let me know !

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea - IMHO you should be using your desktop session's **startup applications**. See for example [How do run a program at startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349962/how-do-run-a-program-at-startup)

Comment: It's not what i want to do actually

Comment: `sudo` is not applicable in rc.local.

Comment: XY Problem. We cannot help you more until you explain what you are trying to accomplish (since you say you don't want to launch Firefox). Whatever it is, @steeldriver is right - rc.local is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I want to launch firefox in full screen at startup on a distant machine on a specific url, it works when i launch rc.local on hand but not when the machine is booting.

I forgot to put my xdotool line there, but it's present in my rc.local

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't run GUI apps via rc.local, it's a command-line only script.
2. All your commands are blocking, append & at the end of each line
3. `sudo` is redundant, because rc.local runs as root already

Comment: Thanks, do you have any clues on how i should do that correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you VNC in, you can run the script/command "locally".

As mentioned by steeldriver ([Rc.Local works manually but not at boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/984126/877732)) and Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy (https://askubuntu.com/a/984164/877732) this doesn't work, but I'm sure it worked once???

I created a bash script, `nano startFirefox.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting Firefox"
/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr &
```

Made it executable `chmod a+x startFirefox.sh` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352939/5165135)

Added it to */etc/rc.local*:

```
fi
/home/pi/startFirefox.sh &
exit 0
```

On newer systems, check it is running `systemctl status rc-local.service` (https://askubuntu.com/a/759821/877732)